# How to transition from managedQuery to LoaderManager/CursorLoader?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, simplecursoradapter, android-loadermanager

I'm developing an Android application that is targeting API level 8 (2.2, Froyo). I'm using a `ContentProvider` and that's simple enough, and I'm using `SimpleCursorAdapter` to fill out my list view, but I noticed in the documentation for [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) that the flagless constructor is deprecated with the following note:

> This constructor is deprecated.
> This option is discouraged, as it results in Cursor queries being performed on the application's UI thread and thus can cause poor responsiveness or even Application Not Responding errors. As an alternative, use LoaderManager with a CursorLoader.

Since I'm targeting API level 8, a `LoaderManager` isn't tied to an `Activity`. The `FragmentActivity` class in the compatibility package does this, but I'm not using Fragments.

My question is: how exactly should I be using `LoaderManager/CursorLoader` in an app targeting a pre-11 API level? Am I forced to transition to Fragments or should I just revert back to the deprecated `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor (but make use of an `AsyncTask` to keep it UI thread friendly, which is what the `CursorLoader` is supposed to do)?

Comment: Check out this blog post: [**Understanding the LoaderManager (part 2)**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/why-you-should-use-loadermanager.html)

Comment: Hello, where is it documented that a LoaderManager is tied to Fragments?  It is simply for retrieving data from a DB.  The model layer is always detached from the UI layer in any sophosticated software paradigm.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky In the documentation for LoaderManager:

`Interface associated with an Activity or Fragment for managing one or more Loader instances associated with it. This helps an application manage longer-running operations in conjunction with the Activity or Fragment lifecycle`

...and the only types of `Activity`s that are associated for older platforms are `FragmentActivity`s.

Comment: Right, the user said: "Am I forced to transition to Fragments".  The answer is NO.  A regular Activity will work fine for these purposes.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Right, but only on the post-fragment APIs. You don't have to transition to `Fragment`s, but you do at least have to transition to an `Activity` that supports `Fragment`s (which is trivial). Not disagreeing, just making it more clear in case anybody is still supporting GB or earlier.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Edit:

I've written fairly extensively about the `LoaderManager` in this [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html). Check it out and let me know if its helpful! :)

---

### Original post:

Definitely, definitely, definitely go with `LoaderManager`. The `CursorLoader` class offloads the work of loading data on a thread, and keeps the data persistent during short term activity refresh events, such as an orientation change. In addition to performing the initial query, the `CursorLoader` registers a `ContentObserver` with the dataset you requested and calls `forceLoad()` on itself when the data set changes, and is thus auto-updating. This is extremely convenient as you don't have to worry about performing queries yourself. Of course it is possible to make use of `AsyncTask` to keep your application UI thread friendly, but it will involve a lot more code... and implementing your class so that it will, for example, retain the loaded `Cursor` over `Activity` won't be simple. The bottom line is that `LoaderManager/Loader` will do this automatically for you, as well as taking care of correctly creating and closing the `Cursor` based on the `Activity` lifecycle.

To use `LoaderManager/CursorLoader` in an app targeting a pre-11 API level, simply use the `FragmentActivity` class in the compatibility package. A `FragmentActivity` is just an `Activity` and has been created for Android compatibility support, and does not require the use of `Fragment`s in your application. Just use `getSupportLoaderManager()` instead of `getLoaderManager()` and you should be all set. You could, of course, implement a parent `FragmentActivity` for each screen and have it displays a its layout in a `Fragment` (by making use of `FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()` in the Activity's `onCreate()` method). This design might make the transition to multi-pane layouts easier if you ever decide to optimize your application for tablets. It's a nice learning experience too :).

This is a pretty nice [**tutorial**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/) too. Try and work your way through it and don't hesitate to leave a comment if you have any other questions.

Comment: **note that there is a [typo](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/comment-page-1/#comment-15832) in the tutorial i posted.** other than that, it's great! :)

Comment: Hmmm, I attempted this, but my view was blank. I must have missed something else. But it's nice to have direction! Thanks! One question though, what exactly is the harm in using CursorLoader directly inside my Activity vs. using it inside of LoaderManager? Out of curiosity, would I be able to simply skip using LoaderManager and reap the same benefits (beyond having to manage my own cursor, that is)?

Comment: There isn't any harm, but you lose all of the benefits of using LoaderManager. For bigger screens it becomes more important that you query on a separate thread since configuration changes involve recreating the entire view layout (and you don't want anything to block this operation on a tablet since layouts are often more complex). By any means you can implement your class to do this on a separate thread using AsyncTask as I mentioned before, but my point is that LoaderManager does this all for you (and manages the cursor too), so its very convenient and its pretty easy to get it working too.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to set up that comes up blank?

Comment: Thank you, that's very informative! To answer your question on the blank view, that was just a lapse of sanity regarding my test data (figures). It works perfectly fine now.

This is definitely easier to implement for async queries!

Comment: The tutorial assumes you have worked through [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/), which probably explains your confusion.

Comment: The tutorial is very confusing in Step 3 where it says **changes to the onCreate() method**. It does not talk about FragmentActivity anywhere. @AlexLockwood I will not say it the best tutorial. It surly need an edit. But +1 for your answer.

Comment: @AlexLockwood - Hey great suggestions. I followed your answer above and the tutorial you referenced. However, I am getting an IllegalArgumentException. I posted my code and question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803754/android-cursorloader-and-loadermanager-error  If you happen to get some time to look at it and see something wrong, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex Lockwood Is LoaderManager and CursorLoader still best practice these days for, say loading SQLite data into a RecyclerView?  Do any of the newer methods like JobIntentService() or JobScheduler offer any major advantages?