# Android: CursorLoader, LoaderManager, SQLite

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-loadermanager

Trying to update my old app in which some methods are deprecated. I found out that if I want to work with ListView that shows data from db, I should use LoaderManager + CursorLoader. CursorLoader works with content providers. So for every table in my db I should create content provider now ? Why should I ? As far as I know content providers is used to share some db information with other applications, but my app dont share any information. So can I use CursorLoader without content providers ???

Comment: Check out my blog post on the subject: [**Understanding the `LoaderManager`**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/why-you-should-use-loadermanager.html)

Comment: @Jim is there any problem with content provider could you help me?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've written a [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/why-you-should-use-loadermanager.html) on this subject. You can also check out this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8900310/844882) for more information. Hopefully it will clear things up for you.

As Barak mentioned, one can implement a `CursorLoader` without content providers by extending `AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor>` class. That said, most of the tutorials and sample code use `ContentProvider`s, and it seems like the Android team encourages its use as well. It's also a lot less complicated than implementing your own class.

That said, if you *really* don't want to use content providers, Dianne Hackborn (one of the Android framework developers, and also known as "hackbod" here on SO) suggests writing your own loader that uses your database class instead of a content provider. The easiest way is just to take the source of the `CursorLoader` class from the compatibility library, and replace provider queries with queries to your own db helper class.

Comment: I think it's worth it to mention that the use of `ContentProvider`s is encouraged only if you plan to provide data to other apps. If you don't (i.e. the data is private to your app), then you are encouraged to use plain SQLite databases. For more info, check the docs for [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html).

Comment: I think "to take the source of the CursorLoader class from the compatibility library, and ..." is the best choice, isn't it?

Comment: I had to extend `CursorLoader` with my own class to handle `OrmLite`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, You can have Custom data loaders which can load objects that you define or any object type or list in that matter.

Just look into the samples from the android sdk for the LoaderCustomSupport.java in the compatibility library samples and demos.