# Example on how to use AsyncTaskLoder to load a cursor from SQLite

Tags: android

I could not find a tutorial on how to use AsyncTaskLoader to load a cursor from a table in SQLite.
Can someone pint me to some documentation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can go for [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) if you find AsyncTaskLoader a bit difficult. It is much easy to implement. Check the above link.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the answer given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017646/android-cursorloader-loadermanager-sqlite). I would suggest to use the Loader framework ([here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) is the tutorial from the developers page). You will have to implement a ContentProvider. If you really want to avoid implementing a ContentProvider, do what is mentioned on the first link.