# Update ListView based on SQLite backed ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I'm a new Android Developer and seem to have gotten in a little over my head.  I am trying to make a listView update when I add more content to the list.

The ListView is based off of a SQLite database.  I was able to get the ListView to be based on the SQLite database by making a ContentProvider for the SQLite database (which was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017646/android-cursorloader-loadermanager-sqlite)).  Now my issue is that I want to update the SQLite database and have it reflected on the ListView.  I am using a loader and according to [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html) if I implemented the loader right it will monitor the data.

I tried updating the SQLite database directly but, that didn't cause the ListView to update without closing and reopening.  My instinct from there is that I should implement the insert method in my contentProvider.  I did a very simple implementation:

```
    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {
        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, mCollectionDB.insertCollection(contentValues));
}
```

Unfortunately, the result of this is my app crashes with a "java.lang.NullPointerException".  This is especially confusing as using the exact same contentValues to make the .insertCollection call from my MainActivity works without issue.

The issue I'm really interested in is how to get my listView to update when I insert data into my SQLite database.  If inserting into the ContentProvider is irrelevant then please ignore that.  I'm not really sure where I went wrong so I'm not sure what other code may be useful, but I'm happy to edit in more code if it'll help.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: My problem was I was declaring a new content provider instead of using getCntentResolver().  See my comment on the accepted answer for more details.

Although, really I was just needed to read more about the related android tools.  So, going through the linked tutorials helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check loader concept. 
You can start with
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#todo

Following are other 2 good tutorials
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/

Comment: From those I found my problem.  I was using: 

`CollectionProvider collectionProvider = new CollectionProvider();
                        collectionProvider.insert(CollectionProvider.CONTENT_URI, valuesNewTable);`  

instead of 

`getContentResolver().insert(CollectionProvider.CONTENT_URI, valuesNewTable);`

Answer (score 1):

Hey [here](http://androidituts.com/android-database-listview-example/) is one example to insert data into sqlite database and display it in list view.
Have a look at it

The idea is simple insert data into database and on click of view button initialize List view with arraylist that contains data already inserted.

You can ask if you have any further queries.