# How to refresh/auto update listview query whithout re-calling activity

Tags: java, android, listview

I create an android app which contain database and listView to display data items of a database. In this app user can add a data at runtime by using button(pop-up) on the same layout of action bar.To generate the added item i need to recall the same activity.My problem is that,whenever the user add a data i want to auto generate/refresh the listVIew without restart/recall the activity.Here is the layout image [image: Please view image]

Suppose this is the main activity
Gradebook.java

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grade_book);
    toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Grade Book");
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gradeList);
    grade_adapter=new Grade_Adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.grade_book_listview1);
    listView.setAdapter(grade_adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
    db_operation_helper=new Db_operation_helper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase=db_operation_helper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor=db_operation_helper.grade_get(sqLiteDatabase);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            String head;
            head=cursor.getString(0);
            DataProvider dataProvider=new DataProvider(head);
            grade_adapter.add(dataProvider);

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"YOU",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            view.setSelected(true);
        }
    });
}
```

And,Here is the pop-up code(pop up when the user click the add button on a action bar)
Pop_up.java

```
public class Grade_pop extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText semorclass;
//    Db_operation_helper grade_db_helper is the class of db opertion
Db_operation_helper grade_db_helper;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
Context context=this;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grade_pop);
    DisplayMetrics dm=new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width,height;
    width=dm.widthPixels;
    height=dm.heightPixels;
    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .4), (int) (height * .155));
    semorclass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.semester);
}
public void additems(View view){

    String sem=semorclass.getText().toString();
    grade_db_helper=new Db_operation_helper(context);
    sqLiteDatabase=grade_db_helper.getWritableDatabase();

        grade_db_helper.grade_add(sem, sqLiteDatabase);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data is saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        grade_db_helper.close();
// Here i recall the activity by intent 
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Grade_book.class));
        finish();
}
```

Here,the Database.java code( data is enter by a contract class)

```
 private static final String Database_name="database_name";
 //    db ver
private static final int Database_version=1;
 private static final String Gradebook_Query=
    "Create Table "+ UserContract.Gradebook_info.Grade_table_name+"("+ UserContract.Gradebook_info.Grade_head+" TEXT);";
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(Gradebook_Query);
    Log.e("Database Operation", "Table Grade Book Created");
    db.execSQL(Monday_query);
}
public void grade_add(String head,SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
//        UserContract class is a java class,Gradebook_info is inner
class,Grade_table_name is the table name
//        all taken from UserContract class
    contentValues.put(UserContract.Gradebook_info.Grade_head, head);
    db.insert(UserContract.Gradebook_info.Grade_table_name, null, contentValues);
    Log.e("Database Operation", "One row is inserted into Gradebook");
}
```

Comment: call `notifyDataSetChanged();` after updating the data in the adapter.

Comment: When you are making Toast "DATA SAVED", again setAdapter to listview(also take data from Database).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185273/update-listview-based-on-sqlite-backed-contentprovider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one this modify your activity code like this :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    listView.setAdapter(grade_adapter);
    db_operation_helper=new Db_operation_helper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase=db_operation_helper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor=db_operation_helper.grade_get(sqLiteDatabase);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
      do {
           String head;
           head=cursor.getString(0);
           DataProvider dataProvider=new DataProvider(head);
           grade_adapter.add(dataProvider);
           grade_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }

}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.grade_book);
toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Grade Book");
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gradeList);
grade_adapter=new Grade_Adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.grade_book_listview1);

registerForContextMenu(listView);    

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"YOU",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        view.setSelected(true);
    }
});
}
```

And Don't call `startActivity()` in your pop_up. Modify addItems() like this:

```
public void additems(View view){

String sem=semorclass.getText().toString();
grade_db_helper=new Db_operation_helper(context);
sqLiteDatabase=grade_db_helper.getWritableDatabase();

    grade_db_helper.grade_add(sem, sqLiteDatabase);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data is saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    grade_db_helper.close();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: I nearly work perfectly except. It display the previously added data and on the next row it display both previously added and newly data data..Its repeat the data display of the previous.

Answer (score 2):

you can try calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your `listView` Activity's `onResume();`finish the pop activity after inserting data in Sqlite.

like this

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
//here you can update the adapter just call notify methods
 grade_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: this is no working . I think there no new data altering to notify.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to refresh ListView then call  grade_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: you can comment this..!!