# What is the best approach for asynchronously loading data from SQLite into an Android ListView?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-loader

I'm new to Android and have successfully implemented an `ArrayAdapter` to display a list of simple objects in a `ListView`. I have also created a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and I'd like to use this to display a list of rows from the database in the `ListView`.

From what I can tell, it seems like I should be using a `Loader` to asynchronously query the data, and act as a middle man between my data and the UI.

The `Loader` and `CursorLoader` documentation only refers to how to achieve this when querying a `ContentProvider`. This led me to think that the best approach may be to create a `ContentProvider` which provides a structured interface to my database - but the Android documentation on creating a `ContentProvider` states:

> You don't need a provider to use an SQLite database if the use is
>   entirely within your own application.

*Are there any particular reasons why I shouldn't write a `ContentProvider`? Unless I'm missing something it seems like this would provide a good abstraction for the data layer and mean I can have all the benefits of using a `CursorLoader` when consuming it.*

*In my case the **database is only for use by my application** - so what alternatives are there and are there any good tutorials which show the process start to finish?*

Thanks!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017646/android-cursorloader-loadermanager-sqlite

Comment: you can use a cursorloader even if your database isnt wrapped in a contentprovider

Comment: @pskink - Thanks I will read this in more detail now. It seems strange to me that you have to write your own subclass of CusorLoader. It seems like a very common thing that people would want.

Comment: @Daniel - how so? The cursor loader seems to require a URI which would only make sense with a ContentProvider?

Comment: @MattWilson so it is better to write a ContentProvider, maybe a bit more effort but it pays off

Comment: @pskink this was my thinking - it seems like quite a good way to do it as it would provide good structure? I guess my fear is that it seems wrong to directly go against the advice about not creating a ContentProvider for "private" data.

Comment: ContentProvider also helps in keeping cursors up to date when inserting, deleting and updating the sqlitedb