# How to Add a extra value to spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

SOLVED HERE IS THE SOLUTION ANSWER http://www.congdegnu.es/2011/06/02/spinners-en-android-tres-formas-de-poblarlos/
I'm populating a spinner from my sqlite database like this:

```
Cursor CS = newDB.rawQuery("Select ID AS _id, Name from Schools",null);
    CS.moveToFirst();
    do{     
        Schools.add(CS.getString(CS.getColumnIndex("_id")));   
    } while(CS.moveToNext());

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Schools);

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

My problem is that I only add an id but how can I add a value to that id so when the value get select I get the id ?

Comment: Do you know about cursor adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) for your spinner instead. Although this has been deprecated since API-11, so you may also want to think about using a [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) with a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html).

An explanation on how to transition to a LoaderManager and CursorLoader can be found here:
[How to transition from managedQuery to LoaderManager/CursorLoader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899497/how-to-transition-from-managedquery-to-loadermanager-cursorloader)

I would recommend you start by using the SimpleCursorAdapter, then if confortable enough, move on to the other method.

Comment: I try this   SimpleCursorAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,CS,new String[] {"Name"},new int[] {android.R.id.text1}); 
 and is not showing data

Comment: I found my answer here ANSWER http://www.congdegnu.es/2011/06/02/spinners-en-android-tres-formas-de-poblarlos/

Answer (score 0):

I think that "schools" is an array containing you own class "school". 
 
You could add a propertie which contains the information. 
 
Or you could use a 2 dimensional array. 
Than you have to set up your arrayadapter to get the information (getter Method). 
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try [Cursor Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)

or

Take a global variable

```
 Hashmap schoolmap=new Hashmap();
```

While inserting data to the list also add to Hashmap like this

```
CS.moveToFirst();
    do{     
        Schools.add(CS.getString(CS.getColumnIndex("_id")));   
        schoolmap.put(CS.getString(CS.getColumnIndex("_id")),CS.getColumnIndex("_id"))
    } while(CS.moveToNext());
```

onSpinner item click get the value like this

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                    int pos, long id) {
              String value=((TextView)view).getText();
              int id=Integer.parseInt(schoolmap.get(value));
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }

    });
```

Comment: i don't understand so i have to add the hash map to my arrayadapter?

Comment: @user2033349 no not like that.....map the values you are showing in the spinner as keys and the respective IDs as values in Hashmap, And from the spinner selection you'll get the value, pass that value as a key to hashmap, so it will give you the respective Id

Answer (score 0):

1) Create an `ArrayList<School>`

2) Add all your Schools to the Arraylist

3) Create a custom adapter like this:

```
public class SchoolAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<School>{

    public SchoolAdapter(Context ctx, List<School> schools){
        super(ctx, 0, schools);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView tv;
        if (convertView == null){
            tv = new TextView(getContext());
        } else {
            tv = (TextView) convertView;
        }
        tv.setTextSize(16);
        final School school = getItem(position);
        tv.setText(school.toString());
        return tv;
    }

}
```

4) Use this in your activity:

```
final SchoolAdapter adapter = new SchoolAdapter(this, schools);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                int pos, long id) {
         School school = adapter.getItem(pos);
         // Do whatever you want with your school            

     }

     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

     }

});
```

Comment: ok but i dont want to get a pos int as id i already have an ID in my sqlite or im missing something? thansk for your time

Comment: I found my answer here ANSWER http://www.congdegnu.es/2011/06/02/spinners-en-android-tres-formas-de-poblarlos/ thanks

Comment: pos is not an id, it refers to the position in the list.