# Loaders - why use them?

Tags: android, android-loader

Could you point out or recommend reading on pros of using [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) regarding network/sqlite requests?

The only implementation - [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) says it uses a [ContentResolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html). ContentResolvers as I read are used in conjunction with ContentProviders, which purpose is to expose inner-application data. It seems a bit messed up to me since I only intend to load data for internal usage. I cant see any point/benefits of using Loaders - what's bad with using ORM tool like [greenDao](http://greendao-orm.com/) in conjunction with plain AsyncTasks?

Are there design benefits? easy DI?

Answer (score 0):

The CursorLoader is a very convinient method for querying because it takes care of the thread in an asyncronously manner. There is a lot of info here about it, you just have to search it. Here are two links that might help you to understand them.

Check inside [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899497/how-to-transition-from-managedquery-to-loadermanager-cursorloader) and full explanation on an [expert blog](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html).

Good luck!